# Filtering data in CartoDB?

Tags: carto, filter

I try to filter multiple values in the same column in CartoDB. I then like to filter on another column.

I do not manage to filter on multiple values in one column in the graphical interface (one value ok, but more I see no way to do this).

I then write the SQL query:

```
    SELECT * FROM bdi_adm2 
WHERE name_1 ILIKE '%bururi%' 
OR name_1 ILIKE '%cancuzo%' 
OR name_1 ILIKE '%karuzi%' 
OR name_1 ILIKE '%makamba%' 
OR name_1 ILIKE '%rutana%' 
OR name_1 ILIKE '%ruyigi%'
```

But then I am not able to filter on another column (it tells me that I have to clear the selection first).

How can I filter through the input box for multiple values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queries and filters cannot be mixed in that way at the moment. A query cannot be reinterpreted in the filters view.

You can add multiples filters on the Filter feature by clicking on the '+' icon that appears below a current filter.

[image]

These filters are, though, built as an **AND** query between them, so results will need to match all the applied filters for your columns.

In my case, the query generated by the following configuration is:
[image]

`SELECT * FROM uk_wine_climate_map_iii_copy WHERE column1 IN ('One')  AND column2 IN ('A','C')`

If you want to add more columns to your filter you can create a query and you just need to concatenate the constraints on your columns that you need.

```
SELECT * FROM bdi_adm2 
WHERE name_1 ILIKE '%bururi%' 
OR name_1 ILIKE '%cancuzo%' 
OR name_1 ILIKE '%karuzi%' 
OR name_1 ILIKE '%makamba%' 
OR name_1 ILIKE '%rutana%' 
OR name_1 ILIKE '%ruyigi%'
OR other_column ILIKE '%something%'
OR extra_column = 'Yes'
OR numerical_column = 25
```